# Wordpress Advanced Custom Fields - Limit A User's Choice To One Option

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress website and as part of the news items, the editor can add either an:

- internal link OR
- external link OR
- file

Currently I have this set up as a repeater field with maximum rows set to 1.

Is it possible if say one value has been entered, to prevent another of the values from being filled in.

E.g. I add an internal link and then try to add an external link.  A message of some sort is then shown to me to say that only one value can be selected at a time.

I know I can add a description to the field with this information but I want to make it idiot proof so that the user can never add more than one value.

Thanks for your time and help in advance.

Comment: Probably more suited at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: have you looked into the `conditional logic` options?

Comment: this is very easy to do with the conditional display options built into ACF as celeriko says...

Comment: Do you mean that you have 3 columns in the repeater row? 1 for each of the three options?

Answer (score 1):

I can't write this in comments but celeriko right. Install types plugin there is ability of conditional logic. You can very easy implement of from backend.

Types: http://wp-types.com/

Reagrds